# Upload file on a subdomain

Tags: php, ftp, copy, subdomain

For my app I decided to change the directory of static and public content to another domain.
However, I had troubles about the copy of files into folders.

I decided to restrict the access of subdomain to a specific path. Indeed, when you log in to the ftp, you can't show the subfolders

So atm, this is what I have :
A domain www.domain.com
A subdomain www.static.domain.com

Ftp logs which only allow me to show the content of www.static.domain.com

Then, I wish to copy files and directories after user's register. I can create folders, but I can't copy files...

The getcwd() function returns me this :
/datas/vol2/xxxx/var/www/domain.com/htdocs

instead of 
/datas/vol2/xxxx/var/www/static.domain.com/htdocs

That's why I can't copy the index.html file at the root of the subdomain to each folders i'm going to create.

Do you have any ideas about that ?

Thanks for answers
T

Comment: Do you have root access? Does your ftp account have the correct rights? is the owner of your domains files/folder the same as your static subdomain?

Comment: Yes i have the root access

Comment: Ok, use your vpn terminal or SSH to check the owner of your files in your domain and subdomain. CD into your directory and enter "ls -l" this returns all folders/files with their owner/group (also check that the owner has read rights of the folders) ... then I should know which ftp server you're using... ProFTPd or Pure FTPd maybe?

Comment: I'm using filezilla with codeigniter and i'm the owner of the files

Comment: If you're logging in, you are in domain.com/htdocs right? can you go out of this directory (..) into ../www/ folder and then into your subdomain? Does your htdocs of your subdomain have the correct read/write rights?

Answer (score 0):

What about the "copy" or "move" Command?